# Program can't start because GX6050R.dll is missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I'm trying to install a program on a Windows 7 machine, but in the end of the installation process, when I press "Finish", I get an error message saying:

> Actrix.exe - System Error
>
> > The program can't start because GX6050R.dll is missing from your computer.
> >     Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

[image: screen shot of installation error message described above]

I have tried reinstalling the program, restarting the computer (before reinstalling) etc., but I can't get this to work.

The sites I find when I Google this suggest I download some "Error repair tool" (not happening).

Any clues as to how I can fix this?

## **UPDATE:**

This is in fact a known problem, but the proposed solution is of little help. It is suggested that I download Windows Installer 4.5. As far as I can see from the [Windows website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942288), Installer 4.5 is not for Windows 7. It seems like the equivalent for Windows 7 is Installer 5.0, but this is not available for download (at least I can't find it).

Also, I had the previous version of this program installed on my computer, so I find it unlikely that the new version should only be available for XP.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the installer as Administrator? Also, if it is an old program then have you tried running it in compatibility mode?

Comment: @James: I have tried starting the Installer using "Run as administrator". The program is released in 2013, so I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: Where did you get the installer from - have you tried redownloading it if possible? Also, try searching your computer to see if the DLL exists anywhere, in which case you might have an incorrect PATH environment variable or something. Alternatively, perhaps try contacting the company that developed or published the software to see if it is a known problem.

Comment: @James: Thanks for replying! I have updated the question with some additional information. I'm on another computer now, so I can't search for the files right now, but I'll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: @James, I've tried searching for the DLL, but it does not exist. =/

Comment: Did you ever find the [Windows Installer 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483)?

Comment: @CharlieRB, I found the installer (I linked to it in the question), but as far as i can see, it's not for Windows 7. "The Windows Installer 4.5 redistributable can be installed on Windows XP Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack 3, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista, Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and Windows Server 2008 in X86, X64 and IA64 flavors." The program I tried to install is now installed properly, and I haven't got the slightest clue why it didn't work to begin with, and why it worked out in the end. =)

Answer (score 0):

1. Find `.dll` file on the disk
2. Copy it to `c:\windows\system32`
3. Open an elevated command-prompt
4. Execute the following commands to register it:

   ```
   cd c:\windows\system32  
   regsvr32 gx6050r.dll
   ```